# Custom error page not working in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-views

I have the following file in `views/errors/404.blade.php`:

```
Error Here!
```

That works as expected when I enter an incorrect URL (I see just the "Error Here!" text).

However, if I update the file to include the following:

```
@extends('layouts.page')

@section('title', @trans('general.error'))

@section('content')

    Error here!

@endsection
```

I do get the "Error here" message, but I'm also seeing the "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." message and the HTML is all messed up. The specified layout (layouts/page.blade.php) exists and is what I used for all other views.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try changing `@trans` to `trans` .. maybe

Comment: Hi @lagbox! Super weird, the translation works with or without the @, however the issue remains even if I remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `page.blade.php` file contained the following:

```
@if(App::environment('local', 'staging'))
    Current route: {{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName() }}<br/>
@endif
```

If I remove the `Current route: {{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName() }}<br/>` portion it works as expected.

Without digging too much, my guess is that `getCurrentRoute()` returns null.